# Is it true that the boundary of an open ball is equal to the boundary of a closed ball, in an arbitrary metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Is my reasoning correct here?

Let $B(x;r)=\{y\in X : d(x,y) < r\}$, $\partial B(x;r)=\{y\in X : d(x,y) = r\}$, $\overline B(x;r)=\{y\in X : d(x,y) \leq r\}$, and $\partial\overline B(x;r)=\{y\in X : d(x,y) = r\}$.

Therefore $$\partial B(x;r)=\{y\in X:d(x,y)=r\}=\partial\overline B(x;r),$$ and the statement is true for every metric space. Additionally, we can consider an open interval $(a,b)=A$ in the real line $\Bbb R$. Then $\partial A=\{a,b\}$, $\overline A=[A,B]$, and $\partial\overline A=\{a,b\}$. Therefore $\partial A=\partial\overline{A}$.

Comment: Yes. By definition, for any set $A$ in a metric space, we have $\partial A=\bar A\setminus A^\circ$ where $\bar A$ is the closure of $A$ and $A^\circ$ is its interior. For your examples, $(\bar A)^\circ=A$, ie, $A^\circ=(\bar A)^\circ$, thus $\partial A=\bar A\setminus (\bar A)^\circ=\partial\bar A$

Comment: You both say that it is true, but the answer below indicates that the two sets are *not* equal. Which is correct?

Comment: What's your definition of a "closed ball" and how do you know $\partial B(x;r) = \{y|d(x,y)=r\}$ and how do you define $\overline A$ and how do you know $\overline B(x;r)$ is a closed ball and/or is equal to $\{y|d(x,y)\le r\}$.  I think your reasoning is correct but I'm not sure which definitions you are using.

Comment: @ZoëS . The first 2 comments are wrong.

Comment: @Quoka    No. You are mistaken. See the A's.

Comment: @learner No. See the  A's.................

Answer (score 3):

No, $\partial B(x;r)$ is **not** necessarily $\{y \in X: d(x,y) = r\}$. E.g. let $X$ be the integers with the metric $d(x,y) = |x-y|$.  For any integer $x$, $B(x; 1) = \{x\}$ and so is its closure; $\partial B(x,1) = \emptyset$.
But $\{y: d(x,y) \le 1\} = \{x-1,x,x+1\}$.

Comment: Note that in this example, however, we still have $\partial B(x;1) = \partial \overline{B}(x;1) = \emptyset$. This can be avoided if we consider $X$ to be $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} (n-1/4,n+1/4) \subset \mathbb{R}$. Then $\partial B(n;3/4) = \{n-1/4,n+1/4\} \neq \partial \overline{B}(n;3/4) = \{n-3/4,n-1/4,n+1/4,n+3/4\}$.

Comment: I'm so confused. So are they equal or not?

Comment: The boundary of an open ball is not necessarily the boundary of the corresponding closed ball.  For another example, let $X = \{0\} \cup [1,2]$.  The boundary of the open ball $B(0;1)$ is empty.  The closed ball $\{x: d(0,x)\le 1\} = \{0,1\}$ has boundary ${1}$.
In the other direction, the open ball $B(2;1)$ has boundary $\{1\}$, but the boundary of the closed ball $\{x: d(2,x)\le 1\} = [1,2]$ is empty.

Comment: Okay. But I’m defining the open/closed ball as {y ∈ X: d(x,y) =r}. Does your reasoning still hold?

Comment: With $=$ that's not a ball, that's a sphere.

Answer (score 0):

Not valid. Examples:

(i). $X=\{x,z\}$ with $d(x,z)=1.$ Then $B(x,1)=\bar B(x,1)=\{x\}$ is open-and-closed so it has empty boundary. But $\{y\in X: d(x,y)=1\}=\{z\}.$

(ii). $X=[-1,1]$ with $d(u,v)=|u-v|.$ Then $\partial B(0,1)=\{-1,1\}$ but $\bar B(0,1)=X$ has empty boundary.