# Metric spaces - proving property of metric on boundary

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Prove that if the point $x$ is on the boundary of the open ball $B(x_0,r)$ then $d(x_0,x)=r$.

I find this difficult because it seems intuitive yet not easy to prove. By definition, if $A\subset X$ then a point $x$ is on the boundary if for all $\epsilon>0$ we have $B(x,\epsilon)\cap A\ne\emptyset$ and also $(X\setminus A)\cap B(x,\epsilon)\ne\emptyset$. However I don't know how to use this definition in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 2):

If $d(x,x_0) <r$ then $x \in B(x_0,r)$ so $x$ is not a boundary point. ($B(x_0,r)$ is open). If $d(x,x_0) >r$  and $s=d(x,x_0) -r$  then there is no point of $B(x_0,r) $ in $B(x,s)$, so $x$ is not  a boundary point.

[If $y \in B(x_0,r) \cap B(x,s)$ then $s+r=d(x_0,x) \leq d(x_0,y)+d(y,x) <r+s$, a contradiction].

Answer (score 0):

Using the definition of a boundary point: For all $\epsilon > 0$ is $B(x,\epsilon)\cap B(x_0,r)\ne\emptyset$, i.e. there is an $y \in X$ with
$$ \tag{$1$}
 d(y, x) < \epsilon \text{ and } d(y, x_0) < r \, ,
$$
and also $(X\setminus B(x_0,r))\cap B(x,\epsilon)\ne\emptyset$, i.e. there is a $z \in X$ with
$$ \tag{$2$}
 d(z, x) < \epsilon \text{ and } d(z, x_0) \ge r \, .
$$

It follows from $(1)$ and the triangle inequality that
$$
 d(x, x_0) \le d(x, y) + d(y, x_0) < \epsilon + r
 \implies \boxed{d(x, x_0) < r+ \epsilon} \, .
$$
and from  $(2)$ and the triangle inequality  that
$$
 r \le d(z, x_0) \le d(z, x) + d(x, x_0) < \epsilon + d(x, x_0)
 \implies \boxed{d(x, x_0) > r- \epsilon} \, .
$$

So we have
$$ 
r - \epsilon < d(x, x_0) < r+ \epsilon
$$
for all $\epsilon > 0$, and that implies $d(x, x_0) = r$.

*Remark:* Note that the reverse implication $d(x, x_0) = r \implies x \in \partial B(x_0, r)$ does not necessarily hold in a metric space. For counterexample, see
[Is it true that the boundary of an open ball is equal to the boundary of a closed ball, in an arbitrary metric space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3154978/is-it-true-that-the-boundary-of-an-open-ball-is-equal-to-the-boundary-of-a-close/3155018#3155018)

Answer (score 0):

We start by defining the boundary of a set.
Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space. Let $A$ be a set in $X$, the boundary of $A$ is defines as
$$\partial A=Cl(A)\setminus Int(A)$$
Where $Cl(A)$ and $Int(A)$ mean closure of $A$ and interior of $A$ respectively.

Now consider a metric space $(X,d)$, a point $a\in X$, and a positive real number $r$ and let
$$A=B_r (a)$$

**Step 1:** We will first prove that for any point $b\in X$,
$$d(a,b)< r \Rightarrow b\notin\partial A$$
we prove this by taking $\delta= r-d(a,b)>0$ and proving that
$$B_\delta (b)\subseteq B_r (a)$$

For any $z\in B_\delta (b)$ we have
$$d(b,z)<\delta$$
$$\Rightarrow d(b,z)<r-d(a,b)$$
Using the triangular inequality we know that
$$d(a,z)\le d(a,b)+d(b,z)$$
$$< d(a,b)+ r-d(a,b)$$
$$\Rightarrow d(a,z)<r$$
$$\Rightarrow z\in B_r(a)$$
$$\Rightarrow B_\delta (b)\subseteq A$$
$$\Rightarrow b \in Int(A)$$
$$\Rightarrow b\notin\partial A$$

**Step 2:** We will now show that for any point $b\in X$,
$$d(a,b)> r \Rightarrow b\notin\partial A$$
we prove this by taking $\delta= d(a,b)-r>0$ and proving that $b\notin Cl(A)$ i.e.
$$B_\delta (b)\cap B_r (a)=\emptyset$$
Assume that $z\in B_\delta (b)\cap B_r (a)$ then
$$d(a,z)<r\text{ and } d(z,b)<\delta$$
now take the triangular inequality
$$d(a,b)\le d(a,z)+d(z,b)$$
$$\Rightarrow d(a,b)< r+\delta$$
$$\Rightarrow d(a,b)< r+d(a,b)-r$$
$$\Rightarrow d(a,b)< d(a,b)\text{ a clear contradiction}$$
$\Rightarrow B_\delta (b)\cap B_r (a)=\emptyset$$
$$\Rightarrow b\notin Cl(A)$$
$$\Rightarrow b\notin\partial A$$

**Conclusion:** Which means that if $b\in \partial A$, then the only possibility left is to have
$$d(a,b)=r$$

Hope this helps